# which ELK(Elastic search,logstash,Kibana) stack version is compatible with java 7

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am setting up Kibana and elastic search for the application build on JDK7.
Which version of Kibana and elastic search will support JDK7 build application?

I have found that elastic search version newer than 2.4 does not support JDK7.https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/setup.html#jvm-version

If it would be right to use this very older version? and if yes then by which kibana version it can be integrated?

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with elasticsearch version 2.4, just go ahead and use it.

```
Version 2.4
```

Make sure you are having Java 7 update 55 or later. Previous versions of Java 7 are known to have bugs that can cause index corruption and data loss. (Based on official documentation)

**Kibana version 4.6.0** is compatible with the elasticsearch version 2.4

https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-6-0-released

Comment: Thank you Pandiyan Cool.

Comment: Feel free to upvote if you thought answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using latest version of ES and Kibana.

Elasticsearch is built using Java, and requires at least Java 8 in order to run. Only Oracle’s Java and the OpenJDK are supported.

If you can only use Java 7 then as you discovered you cannot go higher than ES 2.4